# yfinance's info only returns 3 items instead of the usual long list

Tags: python, yfinance

Up until recently the 3 lines below gave a long list of items, now I get only

```
{'regularMarketPrice': None, 'preMarketPrice': None, 'logo_url': ''}
```

whatever company ticker I use. I have uninstalled and re-installed yfinance, to no avail. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
import yfinance as yf
msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
print(msft.info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it by updating yfinance to the latest version: pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir --pre

Comment: Brilliant! It now works for me too. I had re-installed yfinance before to no avail. It must be the "--no-cache-dir" bit or the "--pre" bit that makes the difference. No idea what these 2 bits mean, but he!, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

yfinance [page](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) makes the following explanation:

> Since December 2022 Yahoo has been encrypting the web data that
> yfinance scrapes for non-market data. Fortunately the decryption keys
> are available, although Yahoo moved/changed them several times hence
> yfinance breaking several times. yfinance is now better prepared for
> any future changes by Yahoo.
>
> Why is Yahoo doing this? We don't know. Is it to stop scrapers? Maybe,
> so we've implemented changes to reduce load on Yahoo. In December we
> rolled out version 0.2 with optimised scraping. Then in 0.2.6
> introduced Ticker.fast_info, providing much faster access to some info
> elements wherever possible e.g. price stats and forcing users to
> switch (sorry but we think necessary). info will continue to exist for
> as long as there are elements without a fast alternative.

Thus, there could be some decryption issues.

Comment: Thanks. Very good to know. But ... yesterday I re-installed yfinance, and calling msft.fast_info results in an error: 'Ticker' object has no attribute 'fast_info'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks - Michael

Comment: I don't think you are doing something wrong. `yfinance` doesn't seem to be stable. Try `msft.history(period="1mo")`.  Refer to the page https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/ to see the commands which could work for you.